# Are static members slower to access than instance members in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

Are static members slower to access than instance members in AS3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So they say...

This guy has made some benchmarks, which you might find interesting:

http://blog.controul.com/2009/04/how-slow-is-static-access-in-as3avm2-exactly/